# Linksys WRVS4400N running real hot and shutting down

Tags: linksys

My Linksys Wireless-N Gigabit Security Router with VPN running firmware Version: V1.1.03 is usually very hot to the touch, especially on the bottom.  I have it standing on its side on my desk in my home office to try and maximize airflow, so I suppose it could be worse.  Sometimes it shuts down for no apparent reason, other than perhaps the "hotness".  (Though I know there are memory leaks in this version of the firmware.)  The specs list the operating temperature range as 0 to 40ºC (32 to 104ºF), and it's less than the max in my office, but sometimes it can get pretty close.  Is this normal for this piece of hardware, or is mine somehow defective?  Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: hmm, can you give us a little more detail on "shuts down"? there are lots of reasons why you might lose network connectivity - is it that, or do you actually see the lights turn off (or turn on in a pattern that suggests it is restarting)?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a sticker on Cisco Routers and switches saying "The surface may be hot" and not to touch them. So I think your case is not a problem. Even my USR router (It is just a DSL router for home use) is getting hot even after one hour but I've never experienced a problem with that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Does the device have an internal fan? From what I could find on the Internet, I can't tell, but even without a fan, the device may have accumulated dust inside which is preventing airflow.